# AngularJS - Using typeahead with ngTagsInput

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typeahead.js, ng-tags-input

This is my `index.html`

```
            <form ng-controller = "emailViewController">
                <tags-input placeholder="To" ng-model="select" typeahead="toPerson for toPerson in to | filter:$viewValue" style="width:95%;">
                </tags-input>
                <br />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" style="width:95%;"><br />
                <textarea style="width:95%;" rows="10"></textarea>
            </form>
```

`emailViewController.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var emailViewController = function (fetchDataService,$scope,$filter) {
        var url = 'app/mock/emails.json';

        fetchDataService.getContent(url)
            .then(function(response){
               $scope.emails = response.data;

                $scope.to = [];

                angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(key, value) {
                   $scope.to.push(key.to);
                })

                $scope.loadEmails('Primary');
          });
         }

    angular.module('iisEmail')
        .controller ('emailViewController',
        ['fetchDataService', '$scope','$filter', emailViewController]);
}());
```

`Typeahead` was working fine until I removed the `input` tag (on which it was an attribute) and added the `tags-input` directive. So, I had `<input placeholder="To" ng-model="select" typeahead="toPerson for toPerson in to | filter:$viewValue" style="width:95%;">` earlier. Now, I have `<tags-input placeholder="To" ng-model="select" typeahead="toPerson for toPerson in to | filter:$viewValue" style="width:95%;">` and it does not work.

I think this happened because `typeahead` only works on `input tags`. Does anyone have ideas on how to make `typeahead` work with `ngTagsInput`?

Just to avoid any confusion, I want to make it clear that, I know how to use `autocomplete` with `ngTagsInput`. My question is specifically targeting problems I am facing using `typeahead` with `ngTagsInput`.

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/B1aV9TLu58a2iGhpTUrN?p=preview

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem using `angular-tags` instead of `ngTagsInput`. `ngTagsInput` does not work with `typeahead`. The best answer that was chosen provides a good explanation of why this is the case. Here is the Plunker with the solution to this issue using `angular-tags` - http://plnkr.co/edit/PaG1k5N37BTOflObnN7K?p=preview

Comment: consider maybe giving a smaller example that shows the problem? a plunkr maybe? :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question @toskv

Comment: I see that the ngTagsInput directive does generate some html, most likely the typeahead attribute doesn't end up on the input element. You should be able to check that in the generated html when running the code. :)

Comment: btw, you also have an error, the emailViewController function lacks a } to close properly. maybe that's it.

Comment: @toskv I think you did not understand my question. I have added more detail, so hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: @toskv Thanks for pointing out the error. I fixed it, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87924/discussion-between-toskv-and-michelle).

Comment: I think I understood, and my previous answer as to why it is not working seems to be correct. Check out this plunkr :) if you'll have a look at the generated code the typeahead attribute remains on the ng-input-tags element and since that's not the input your typing in it will not work. http://plnkr.co/edit/B1aV9TLu58a2iGhpTUrN?p=preview

Comment: So you mean there is no way to achieve this functionality? @toskv

Comment: I don't see a way using ng-tags-input. angular-tags does use the ui.boostrap.typeahead though, maybe that works?

Comment: I tried that already. I couldn't get it to work. It gave me a bunch of errors, and that's why I used `ngTagsInput` instead.

Comment: maybe we can work trough those errors. care to join me in chat? :)

Comment: it works for me, I made another plunkr. Make sure you are using model and not ng-model, that's what broke it for me. http://plnkr.co/edit/DmuuzM?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ngTagsInput** will not work with **ui.bootstrap.typeahead** because it generates the input elements itself and the **typeahead** attribute doesn't end up on the generated input element.

```html
<tags-input placeholder="To" ng-model="select" typeahead="toPerson for toPerson in to | filter:$viewValue" style="width:95%;">
```

ends up being:

```html
<tags-input placeholder="To" ng-model="select" typeahead="toPerson for toPerson in to | filter:$viewValue" style="width:95%;" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-max-tags ng-valid-min-tags ng-valid-leftover-text" aria-autocomplete="list"
aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-5-8574">
  <div class="host" tabindex="-1" ng-click="eventHandlers.host.click()" ti-transclude-append="">
    <div class="tags" ng-class="{focused: hasFocus}">
      <ul class="tag-list">
        <!-- ngRepeat: tag in tagList.items track by track(tag) -->
      </ul>
      <input class="input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" autocomplete="off" ng-model="newTag.text" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" ng-keydown="eventHandlers.input.keydown($event)" ng-focus="eventHandlers.input.focus($event)" ng-blur="eventHandlers.input.blur($event)"
      ng-paste="eventHandlers.input.paste($event)" ng-trim="false" ng-class="{'invalid-tag': newTag.invalid}" ng-disabled="disabled" ti-bind-attrs="{type: options.type, placeholder: options.placeholder, tabindex: options.tabindex, spellcheck: options.spellcheck}"
      ti-autosize="" type="text" placeholder="To" spellcheck="true" style="width: 20px;"><span class="input" style="visibility: hidden; width: auto; white-space: pre; display: none;">To</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</tags-input>
```

**ngTagsInput** does not seem to provide a way for this to be achieved either. Since it provides it's own search mechanism it probably doesn't allow using an external one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to recreate the plunker you created yesterday (http://plnkr.co/edit/DmuuzM?p=preview). However, I am having problems doing that. I don't get any errors, but their is no output either. Do you have any ideas ? Here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/PaG1k5N37BTOflObnN7K

Comment: yep, you are missing **ng-app** somewhere in in your html ;) @Michelle

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that. Do you know why it is not letting me enter any values that are not in the `$scope.to` variable?

Comment: I figured it out. Just needed to add the `addable` option to the directive. This is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/PaG1k5N37BTOflObnN7K?p=preview

Comment: yup.. if you are happy with the answer please mark it as the solution :)